# react-router-dom not working as intended

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to achieve this(V3)

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="*" component={Whoops404}/>
</Router>
```

with V4 of react-router using  react-router-dom but i'm unable to do that, when i try this

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Route path="/" component={App}/>
        <Route path="*" component={Whoops404}/>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

it renders all the routes in the block instead. am i doing wrong?

****EDIT****
Thank you guys.I have wrapped the routes with a Switch component,and its working fine but when i navigate to `localhost:3000/jjj` or other routes aside the `http://localhost:3000/` the component App still displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems the "/" route is included in "*".

Try:

To render the / and not the others below, in case you trying to render only "/" and getting this side effect.

(Edit: include commment here:)
If does not solve, try to make render only single route with Switch:

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/about" render={ () => <About title='About' /> } />
  <Route path="/costumers" component={Costumers} /> 
  <Route component={NotFound} /> 
 </Switch>  
</BrowserRouter />
```

Comment: If does not solve, try to make render only single route with *Switch*:   <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" render={ () => <About title='About' /> } />
        <Route path="/costumers" component={Costumers} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter />

Comment: Thank you.I have wrapped the routes with a Switch component,and its working fine but when i navigate to localhost:3000/jjj or other routes aside the http://localhost:3000/ the component App still displays.which is not supposed to be.

Comment: did you tried the exact props as would be in <Route exact  path="/" component={App}/>

Comment: @ dpetrini thanks.its working fine now

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your routes with Switch component. So it can match one of the routes. You can also omit 'path="*".

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
  <Route component={Whoops404}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you.I have wrapped the routes with a Switch component,and its working fine but when i navigate to `localhost:3000/jjj` or other routes aside the `http://localhost:3000/` the component App still displays.which is not supposed to be.

Comment: because path "/" is included in '/jjj' you need to specify exact property for Route. So only when "/" exactly is matching - you render the component.